# Java getting the Enum name given the Enum Value

Tags: java, enums, enumeration

How can I get the name of a Java Enum type given its value?

I have the following code which works for a **particular** Enum type, can I make it more **generic**?

```
public enum Category {

    APPLE("3"), 
    ORANGE("1"), 

    private final String identifier;

    private Category(String identifier) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return identifier;
    }

    public static String getEnumNameForValue(Object value){
        Category[] values = Category.values();
        String enumValue = null;
        for(Category eachValue : values) {
            enumValue = eachValue.toString();

            if (enumValue.equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                return eachValue.name();
            }
        }
        return enumValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a special reason why you want to use something other than the name() of the Enum for looking them up? That would confuse a lot of people, and you also cannot use a simple `Category.valueOf(name)`.

Comment: Really can we make it more generic? I am using a lot of `nameOf(String name)`, now for each I will write a `*Enum.values().stream().filter(...).findAny().get()`, which is so annoying.

Answer (score 56):

You should replace your `getEnumNameForValue` by a call to the [`name()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name()) method.

Comment: @Jukia: Also, consider overriding `toString()`: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#toString%28%29

Comment: @trashgod: She is overriding toString

Comment: @Thilo: My error; thanks. @Julia: Sorry about misspelling your name.

Comment: @trashgod: Julia wanted to pass the value. How to pass the value as parameter in name() function ?

Comment: @kayeshparvez: I've used a `Map` of `values()`, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2570265/230513).

Answer (score 48):

Try below code

```
public enum SalaryHeadMasterEnum {

    BASIC_PAY("basic pay"),
    MEDICAL_ALLOWANCE("Medical Allowance");

    private String name;

    private SalaryHeadMasterEnum(String stringVal) {
        name=stringVal;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }

    public static String getEnumByString(String code){
        for(SalaryHeadMasterEnum e : SalaryHeadMasterEnum.values()){
            if(e.name.equals(code)) return e.name();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now you can use below code to retrieve the Enum by Value

```
SalaryHeadMasterEnum.getEnumByString("Basic Pay")
```

Use Below code to get ENUM as String

```
SalaryHeadMasterEnum.BASIC_PAY.name()
```

Use below code to get string Value for enum

```
SalaryHeadMasterEnum.BASIC_PAY.toString()
```

Comment: `code == e.name` is not going to work the way you meant it to, should be `e.name.equals(code)` instead

Comment: Well, yes: `SalaryHeadMasterEnum.getEnumByString("basic pay")` does work, but relies on the JVM merging String literals. Stuff like `SalaryHeadMasterEnum.getEnumByString(new StringBuilder("basic ").append("pay").toString())` does not, but should IMHO. Using `String.equals()` would make both work ;-)

Comment: - for comparing strings with == which is bad and for using a variable 'name' with a different meaning than the 'name()' method

Answer (score 5):

Try, the following code..

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return this.name();
    }
```

Comment: This should work well, but why call the function `toString()` instead of `getName()` (Or something similar) ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the below code, it will return the Enum name from Enum value.

```
public enum Test {

    PLUS("Plus One"), MINUS("MinusTwo"), TIMES("MultiplyByFour"), DIVIDE(
            "DivideByZero");
    private String operationName;

    private Test(final String operationName) {
        setOperationName(operationName);
    }

    public String getOperationName() {
        return operationName;
    }

    public void setOperationName(final String operationName) {
        this.operationName = operationName;
    }

    public static Test getOperationName(final String operationName) {

        for (Test oprname : Test.values()) {
            if (operationName.equals(oprname.toString())) {
                return oprname;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return operationName;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test test = Test.getOperationName("Plus One");
        switch (test) {
        case PLUS:
            System.out.println("Plus.....");
            break;
        case MINUS:
            System.out.println("Minus.....");
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Nothing..");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In such cases, you can convert the values of enum to a List and stream through it. 
Something like below examples. I would recommend using **filter()**.

**Using ForEach**:

```
List<Category> category = Arrays.asList(Category.values());
category.stream().forEach(eachCategory -> {
            if(eachCategory.toString().equals("3")){
                String name = eachCategory.name();
            }
        });
```

**Or, using Filter**:

When you want to find with code:

```
List<Category> categoryList = Arrays.asList(Category.values());
Category category = categoryList.stream().filter(eachCategory -> eachCategory.toString().equals("3")).findAny().orElse(null);

System.out.println(category.toString() + " " + category.name());
```

When you want to find with name:

```
List<Category> categoryList = Arrays.asList(Category.values());
Category category = categoryList.stream().filter(eachCategory -> eachCategory.name().equals("Apple")).findAny().orElse(null);

System.out.println(category.toString() + " " + category.name());
```

Hope it helps! I know this is a very old post, but someone can get help.

Comment: A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "orElse()" can return null in case of "When you want to find with name:" flow.

Answer (score 1):

```
enum MyEnum {
    ENUM_A("A"),
    ENUM_B("B");

    private String name;
   
    private static final Map<String,MyEnum> unmodifiableMap;

    MyEnum (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    static {
        Map<String,MyEnum> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, MyEnum>();
        for (MyEnum instance : MyEnum.values()) {
            map.put(instance.getName().toLowerCase(),instance);
        }
        unmodifiableMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }
    public static MyEnum get (String name) {
        return unmodifiableMap.get(name.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

Now you can use below code to retrieve the Enum by Value

MyEnum.get("A");

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's better to provide the required method in the enum itself. This is how I fetch Enum Name for a given value. This works for CONSTANT("value") type of enums.

```java
public enum WalletType {
    UPI("upi-paymode"),
    PAYTM("paytm-paymode"),
    GPAY("google-pay");

    private String walletType;
        WalletType(String walletType) {
            this.walletType = walletType;
        }
    
    public String getWalletType() {
        return walletTypeValue;
    }
    
    public WalletType getByValue(String value) {
        return Arrays.stream(WalletType.values()).filter(wallet -> wallet.getWalletType().equalsIgnoreCase(value)).findFirst().get();
    }
}
```

e.g. `WalletType.getByValue("google-pay").name()`
this will give you - GPAY