# How to facilitate Netbeans Designer to load JPanel-s that use an enum reverse-lookup using hashmap?

Tags: java, enums, hashmap, netbeans-8, designer

This has become a [Dorothy Dix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorothy_Dix) as I found the root of the matter while I was composing this question.  Nevertheless, I decided to post it because it had everyone in our office stumped and I could find nothing helpful in the google or stackoverflow searches.  This is a good example of once you ask the right question, you may see the light.

While the title *might* sounds complicated, it is a really simple problem that seemed to have no answer.  At the centre of this is an `enum`:

**`Status`**

```
    public enum Status 
    {
        INVALID     ( "INVALID"  ),
        ISSUED      ( "Issued"   ),
        CANCELLED   ( "Cancelled");

        private final   String displayName;

        private final static    Map<String,Status>    displayMap = new HashMap( 4 );


        private Status( String display  ){
            this.displayName = display;
            mapDisplayName( this.displayName, this );
        }


        public String getDisplayName(){
            return displayName;
        }

        public static Status parseString( String statusStr ) {
            return displayMap.get(  statusStr );
        }

        private static void mapDisplayName( final String displayName, final Status state ){
            displayMap.put( displayName,  state );
        }
    }
```

The idea of course is to use the `displayMap` as a reverse-lookup.  Nothing to do with the `getDisplayName()` method at all.

This enum's  `getDisplayName()` call is used in a sub-panel to initialise a **static** array used with a combobox, like:

```
    public class JPanelStatus extends javax.swing.JPanel { 

        private final       String[]    STATUS_LABELS = {
                                            Status.ISSUED     .getDisplayName(),
                                            Status.CANCELLED  .getDisplayName()
                                        };

        public JPanelStatus(){
            initComponents();
              :
            jComboBoxStatus.setModel( new DefaultComboBoxModel<>( STATUS_LABELS ) );
              :
        }
       :
    }
```

Which is referenced in the main JPanel.  When I view this `JPanelStatus`  sub-panel in the Netbeans Designer, it works fine.  As does the [`Preview Design`] function.

However when I load the main form, it fails and the exception show an initialisation failure:

```
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class au.com.project.State
    at au.com.project.client.JPanelStatus.<init>(JPanelStatus.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  ... ... ...
```

The Netbeans IDE log added the following extra information :-p

```
INFO: Could not initialize class au.com.project.State
```

Through a process of elimination -- Commenting-out unrelated code -- I discovered the form will load once I comment-out the HashMap `put()` call in the State enum.

"*That is interesting*.", I say.  It looked like a side-effect from the `put()`.  And in away it is -- A small [Spock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spock_(testing_framework)) which quickly gave me the same error from the command line without the JPanel and without Netbeans.

The error is caused by me, trying to use a HashMap from within the Enum constructor.  It won't work as written.

So I changed the title to hit at the true problem -- Which is actually, how to use a HashMap to do a reverse-lookup for an enum?

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from how the HashMap is declared within the `Status` enum due to HOW enums are initialised.

The first thing in a Java Enum must be the list of values, here: "INVALID", "ISSUED", and "CANCELLED".  The next thing everyone needs to know is that there is a *secret* Java  stage that runs first during Object creation (Class or Enum).  Init is dumb, is runs linearly through the declarative code first-come, first-served.

The first 3 x statements of an enum call the constructor -- That means the statement:

```
    private final static  Map<String,Status>  displayMap = new HashMap( 4 );
```

Has NOT yet been executed, and `displayMap` is **null**.  Also, a `static { }` block is executed in that same 1-2-3-... sequence and does not work either.

Unfortunately none of the Netbeans/Designer stack-trace or IDE log reported a NullPointerException -- The unit test does.  Once you have a NPE, it focuses the mind.  `displayMap` is uninitialised when the first constructor call is made.

**Solution**: The displayMap cannot be **`static final`**, because you may not initialise static members in a constructor.  It must be initialised on the first call, using some variation of the example shown:

**`Status`**

```
    public enum Status
    {
        INVALID     ( "INVALID"  ),
        ISSUED      ( "Issued"   ),
        CANCELLED   ( "Cancelled");

        private static    Map<String,Status>   displayMap;

        private Status( String display  ){
            this.displayName = display;
            mapDisplayName( this.displayName, this );
        }
          :

        private static void mapDisplayName( final String displayName, final Status state ){
            if( null ==  displayMap  ){
                displayMap = new HashMap( 7 );
            }
            displayMap.put( displayName,  state );
        }
    }
```

And then it all runs quite smoothly.

**Caveat**:

Do NOT assign `null` in the displayMap declaration -- That was counter productive:

- The `if( null ==  displayMap  ){...}` block successfully assigns the HashMap during the first call to the Enum constructor.
- After all the enum values declarations are processed.
- Init will call any initialises for declared variables.
- If `displayMap = null;` is declared it replaces the populated HashMap, with 3 x values, with a new empty HashMap. *grrr*

Possibly related question:

- [Reverse lookup for Java Enums with more than one value per key/constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26338237/108350) ... I felt that a HashMap would deliver the reverse-lookup of multiple strings a lot more easily.

Comment: Also consider a [_static initializer_](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7), seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2570374/230513).

Comment: IF you could do that, it needs to be used before the first enum constant, to avoid the forward reference.